# How to start the Service of default music player

Tags: android

I just need to start the SERVICE of default Music player. I can play the song if the service is started but have no idea how to start the service of music player

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
i.putExtra("command", "play");
context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/song.mp3");
it.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/mp3");
startActivity(it);
```

or

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "1");   
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);   
startActivity(it);
```

or You can simply pass the url to Media Player like this,

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("your url here");
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setDataAndType(myUri, "audio/*"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Extracted from https://snipt.net/Martin/android-intent-usage/

I haven't tested myself.